# Restoring the Windows Github Powershell shortcut

Tags: windows-7, git, powershell, github

I have Github for Windows installed (Win7 x64). It also came with a handy shortcut that allowed launching a Git-optimized Powershell instance (which also displayed information such as the git file status in the prompt when in a tracked folder).

I deleted that shortcut a while ago and now I'm trying to restore it. I have found the script it was executing (shell.ps1 in the app folder), but trying to run it yields several rather ugly errors, such as:

```
Set-Alias : The AllScope option cannot be removed from the alias 'cat'.
At C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1:11 char:10
+ set-alias <<<<  cat        get-content
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (cat:String) [Set-Alias], SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AliasAllScopeOptionCannotBeRemoved,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAliasCommand
```

I can simply use an alternative (like the msys shell), but I'm really curious as to why the PowerShell version isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to hack together a solution, by manually loading my posh-git in my profile (the `Import-Module $env:posh_git` command wasn't working and was throwing a nasty error about $env:posh_git not being a module):

```
. (Resolve-Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\GitHub\shell.ps1")
. (Resolve-Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\GitHub\PoshGit_e0fc5e56ff55708a890f408f03656f758fa0ba8a\profile.example.ps1")
```

...and by commenting out all the default aliases in my default profile file located in (`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`). It worked without this last change as well, but Poweshell kept showing a ton of errors when starting up. Strangely enough, aliases such as `cat` and `ls` still work.

Answer (score 1):

Error suggest collision between your profile and shell.ps1.
This particular one is probably because you have `cat` alias defined in your profile, and it's trying to overwrite the one in `shell.ps1`

I would follow suggestion from this script itself:

```
Generally you would run this from your Powershell Profile like this:

. (Resolve-Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\GitHub\shell.ps1")
```

Anyways: the heart of this is not this script, it's module that comes with it, so be sure to add one more line in your profile:

```
Import-Module $env:posh_git
```

*That* is the piece that handles prompt and other elements.

If you want to avoid using profile - just use `-noprofile` switch on `powershell.exe`.

Comment: I've added those commands in my profile, but they only seem to affect the x86 version of the powershell. The x64 instance apparently ignores that file, even though entering $profile shows the same profile filename as the x86 version. Moreover, now I'm getting another error in the x86 version: `Import-Module : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is null.`, on the Import-Module line.

Comment: It should not matter with version of PS you use (x86/ x64), but just to be sure - you can always dot-source script directly from console. Error you get from Import-Module suggests that you are not dot-sourcing script though: `. Shell.ps1` has very different effect than `Shell.ps1`.

Answer (score 1):

See the answers to *https://stackoverflow.com/q/17457182/95580*; the following command worked for me:

```
%LocalAppData%\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --reinstall-shortcuts
```